# Merging two identical MySQL database tables that use Auto Increment values for customer_id

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a multisite zen cart where it has one single admin and database, but with two separate customer facing sites.

I'm at the point where I need to merge customer data from the two old sites now, but not sure on how to manage the data merge.

This is the structure of one of the tables that needs to be merged:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zen_customers` (
`customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`customers_gender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_firstname` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_lastname` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_dob` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001-01-01 00:00:00',
`customers_email_address` varchar(96) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_nick` varchar(96) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_default_address_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`customers_telephone` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_fax` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_newsletter` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_group_pricing` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`customers_email_format` varchar(4) DEFAULT 'TEXT',
`customers_authorization` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`customers_referral` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_paypal_payerid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_paypal_ec` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`COWOA_account` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`customers_id`),
KEY `idx_email_address_zen` (`customers_email_address`),
KEY `idx_referral_zen` (`customers_referral`(10)),
KEY `idx_grp_pricing_zen` (`customers_group_pricing`),
KEY `idx_nick_zen` (`customers_nick`),
KEY `idx_newsletter_zen` (`customers_newsletter`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In database one, customers_id has records from 1 to 29719, and database 2 has records from 1 to 38117.

I need to combine both of these tables into one, with the customers_id value going from 1 to 67836.

Is there a way to modify the AI value in database 2 so that it adds 29719 to each row, thus keeping them sequential, or alternatively, a method to merge the databases using UNION, but with the AI values being correctly updated?

I did try something simple like

```
CREATE TABLE zen_customers
(SELECT * FROM site1_customers)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM site2_customers);
```

but I just ended up with duplicate customer_id values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there a way to modify the AI value in database 2 so that it adds 29719 to each row ..." -- Yes, that would be a simple `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE site2_customers
       SET customers_id = customers_id + 29719;
```

"... or alternatively, a method to merge the databases using UNION, but with the AI values being correctly updated ..." -- Yes, simply add the number when `SELECT`ing:

```
CREATE TABLE zen_customers
AS
SELECT customers_id,
       ...
       cowoa_account
       FROM site1_customers
UNION ALL
SELECT customers_id + 29719,
       ...
       cowoa_account
       FROM site2_customers;
```

You can additionally replace the literal `29719` with a subquery getting the maximum ID from the first table: `(SELECT max(customers_id) FROM site1_customers)`

I assumed that this is a one time exercise to move and unify the data and you don't intend to keep the two old ones and you don't mean to do this as a form of replication between the three databases. That would be more complicated.

And, since you're not mentioning it, I assume you only want to move the customers themselves but no data that references the customers. If you have data referencing the customers you also need to change the foreign key values to match the right customer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, it is a one time only process. And I do need to move data that references those customer_id values. customers_info for instance uses the customer_id to match the data, but knowing what I do from your answer, I can update those values by adding the 29719 to them.